# Migrate Spring Boot 1.5.8 to 2.1.5 -- Gradle issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Migrating from Spring Boot 1.5.8 to 2.1.5, getting the error message:

> Could not set unknown property 'sourceCompatibility' for project ':api' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

If I comment that line, I get the error message:

> Could not set unknown property 'targetCompatibility' for project ':api' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

If I comment that line, I get the error message:

> Could not find method jar() for arguments [build_4wobgm6qykoy29e0in3cntga8$_run_closure2@1fc9b06d] on project ':api' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

So something is just not right here. I have two `build.gradle` files, one in my root, one in `api`:

**/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.jfrog.bintray' version '1.8.4'
}

apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/git-version.gradle"

version getVersionFromGit()

group 'com.my_org.my_proj'

apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/bintray-vars.gradle"

subprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.8.1'
}
```

**/api/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'           version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'    version '1.0.7.RELEASE'
}

group = rootProject.group
version = rootProject.version

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/my-org/spring-utils' }
}

apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/checkstyle.gradle"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

jar {
    archiveName = 'api.jar'
    baseName = project.name
    version = project.version
}

test {
    doFirst {
        environment "BUILD_NUMBER", "1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    def springBoot = '2.1.5.RELEASE'

    runtime     group: 'org.springframework.boot',              name: 'spring-boot-properties-migrator',    version: springBoot

    compile     group: 'org.flywaydb',                          name: 'flyway-core',                        version: '5.2.4'

    compile     group: 'org.hibernate',                         name: 'hibernate-java8',                    version: '5.4.3.Final'

    compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',              name: 'spring-boot-starter-web',            version: springBoot
    compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',              name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',       version: springBoot
    compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',              name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest',      version: springBoot
    compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',              name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail',           version: springBoot
    compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',              name: 'spring-boot-starter-freemarker',     version: springBoot

    testCompile group: 'junit',                                 name: 'junit',                              version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot',              name: 'spring-boot-starter-test',           version: springBoot
    testCompile group: 'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions',   name: 'flyway-spring-test',                 version: '4.2.0.2'
}
```

I'm clearly missing something here. I've been following the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) as well as Googling, of course. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't applied the `java` plugin to your `api` sub-project so the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` properties that it adds to the project are missing as is the `jar` task that it defines.

Adding `id java` to the `plugins` block at the top of `api/build.gradle` should fix the problem.

Comment: Yep, thank you. This worked before, with the `java` plugin in the root only so I guess the plugins are not inherited any more? Seems strange though since I'm using the same version of Gradle ... ?

Comment: Spring Boot 1.x's Gradle Plugin applied the `java` plugin for you. In 2.x, to make things more flexible, it now reacts to plugins being applied rather than applying them for you.